# Understanding the error "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm completely new into coding/Swift and I know this question asked a lot. I searched and I read but I don't understand it completely.

I connected an UIImageView to my viewcontroller :

```
@IBOutlet var bi01: UIImageView!
```

I set an image via Xcode interface but just in case I also set same image via code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    bi01.image = //image
}
```

So as far as I know bi01 is not nil at this point?

I used a button to change bi01's image :

```
@IBAction func bb01(_ sender: UIButton) {
    updatebi01()
}
```

And created an array for it :

```
let oneToTwo = [image1, image2, image3]
```

So this function works if I write in viewcontroller.swift :

```
func updatebi01() {
    bi01.animationImages = oneToTwo
    bi01.animationDuration = 0.3
    bi01.animationRepeatCount = 1
    bi01.startAnimating()
}
```

So far no problem. But I want to use same function for many pictures, so I create a new swift file and move this function there, I also created an instance for viewcontroller :

```
import Foundation

var screenInstance = ViewController()

func updatebi01() {
    screenInstance.bi01.animationImages = oneToTwo
    screenInstance.bi01.animationDuration = 0.3
    screenInstance.bi01.animationRepeatCount = 1
    screenInstance.bi01.startAnimating()
}
```

And after this when I try that button, xcode give me this famous error in this line :

```
screenInstance.bi01.animationImages = oneToTwo
```

Now, I can just use this code inside viewcontroller.swift, I can handle this problem with ignoring my second attemp/way. But I don't understand the problem itself.

I just want to learn/understand this, it's the same code. It works inside viewcontroller.swift but not works outside of it.

Comment: Simple ...
bi01 is not exist in screenInstance !

Comment: How you are calling updatebi01() from viewController, and secondly var screenInstance = ViewController() created new instanace not uses running

Comment: if u want to make your function in another script. u have to pass the view controller to it. e.g., func updatebi01(myVC: UIViewController){myVC.bi01.animationImages = myVC.oneToTwo}

But i think this way not good at all. it's completely customized to your view controller so why to put your function out

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is not because you do this outside the view controller but because of how you instantiate a view controller and possibly the time at which you call `updatebi01()`. This is not a problem with force-unwrapping but the view controller pipeline.

First of all if you are having outlets `@IBOutlet` I expect you are using storyboards. To instantiate a view controller from storyboard you need to set an identifier in the storyboard and then use it like:

```
var screenInstance = UIStoryboard(name: "fileNameHereWithoutExtension", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "idYouSetUpInStoryboard") as! ViewController
```

So a very quick explanation: By just calling a default constructor as you did `ViewController()` none of the fields are really added. Instance of `ViewController` could possibly have completely different designs and could be instantiated by multiple storyboards or identifier. So what you did is just created a class. In you case you could do something like:

```
var screenInstance: ViewController = {
    let controller = ViewController()
    controller.bi01 = {
        let view = UIImageView()
        view.frame = CGRect.zero
        controller.view.addSubview(view)
        return view
    }()
    return controller    
}()
```

This makes sense now. Since you are doing it programmatically you also need to satisfy all parameters of your class. Since you are force-unwrapping `bi01` you are saying "whoever is instantiating instance of this class needs to ensure that `bi01` will always be set". So set it.

I hope that clears the part about doing it programmatically. But let us now assume you are using storyboards. Let's look at the following code:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
viewController.bi01.animationImages = oneToTwo
```

Now the view controller is correctly instantiated and if `bi01` is `nil` there is an issue in the storyboard. But there is a trick: The `bi01` will in fact be instantiated just before the `viewDidLoad` was called so in most cases it WILL be `nil` just after it has been created. You need to wait for the view controller to actually load.

So don't access the views outside the view controller. What you need is something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet private var bi01: UIImageView! // Note private

    var animationData: (images: [UIImage], duration: TimeInterval, repeatCount: Int)!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        bi01.animationImages = animationData.images
        bi01.animationDuration = animationData.duration
        bi01.animationRepeatCount = animationData.repeatCount
        bi01.startAnimating()
    }
}
```

Now you call:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
viewController.animationData = (oneToTwo, 0.3, 1)
```

and your view controller will do the rest when it needs to.

To explain the last part, the `viewDidLoad` will call after the setter to `animationData`. In fact, view did load is called when adding the controller in window hierarchy. So the most common would be doing:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
viewController.animationData = (oneToTwo, 0.3, 1)
present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

You could also argue that you could access the view by doing something like:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
present(viewController, animated: true) {
    viewController.bi01... // This will work
}
```

but the problem is that the block is called after the view is presented, which is after the animation. That means user will first see defaults and when animation ends the views will suddenly change to reflect the data you are setting. View did load on the other hand will be called just before the animation starts.

There is much more to it but I hope this clears a few issues for you.

Comment: @luk2302 I updated the answer to add info about what you are asking. The bottom line is that "yes", it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so when you create a variable `var screenInstance = ViewController()`, you are only creating a variable of `ViewController` type. 
This variable Doesn't have reference of your viewController which is currently in memory. remember that in iOS Swift, when you instantiate / present or push a viewController, a new instance is created in memory. and   for accessing a viewController outside the class, you have to pass it's reference to its variable.

```
class animationImage: NSObject {
    func updatebi01(viewController : UIViewController) {
        let screenInstance = viewController as! ViewController // or your viewController
        screenInstance.bi01.animationImages = screenInstance.oneToTwo
        screenInstance.bi01.animationDuration = 0.3
        screenInstance.bi01.animationRepeatCount = 1
        screenInstance.bi01.startAnimating()
    }
    }
```

You can call this method from your ViewController like.

```
animationImage.updatebi01(viewController : self)
```

You will also have to change the parameter of this functions and send image as well with viewController's reference.

so let me know if you didn't get this.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is take UIViewController as input paramter like this one

```
func updatebi01(screenInstance: UIViewController) {
    screenInstance.bi01.animationImages = oneToTwo
    screenInstance.bi01.animationDuration = 0.3
    screenInstance.bi01.animationRepeatCount = 1
    screenInstance.bi01.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: this array "oneToTwo" doesn't exist also so u need to access it from the VC